# How to configure a CORS API Gateway trigger from AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

All I want is deploying a github page which launches a cross site `post` request with payload `{"statement":"select * from t"}` to aws lambda API url like `https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/default/foo`. So I create a aws lambda, write some code and create a `API Gateway`  trigger.

When I test my page I found the OPTIONS request is successful but the header is like

```
apigw-requestid: WjJcajPTtjMEPTw=
content-length: 0
date: Mon, 08 Aug 2022 14:50:30 GMT
xxxx: aaaa
```

As you can see, the `xxxx` header is OK but the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header not. This caused the POST request failed.

the aws lambda code:

```
exports.handler = async (event,context, callback) => {
    // I add this because the browser make a OPTIONS request first before axios.post()
    if (event.httpMethod == 'OPTIONS') {
      return {
        headers: {
          "xxxx":"aaaa",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
        statusCode: 200,
      }
    }
    // handle POST case
}
```

the API Gateway trigger setting:

```
API type: HTTP
Authorization: NONE
CORS: Yes
Detailed metrics enabled: Yes
Method: ANY
Resource path: /foo
Service principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
Stage: default
Statement ID: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Why are you trying to handle the OPTIONS request in a Lambda function, instead of configuring CORS in the API Gateway settings https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: @MarkB If I don't, the OPTIONS request will trigger my code and raise error

Comment: Look at the link I posted please. You can let API Gateway handle the OPTIONS requests for you.

Comment: @MarkB I 've read it and `Enabling CORS support for Lambda or HTTP proxy integrations` is my case. content: `you can still set up the required OPTIONS response headers in API Gateway. However, your backend is responsible for returning the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers, because a proxy integration doesn't return an integration response.` I believe this means I need to handle OPTIONS in my code